# openmpi multiple hosts error

Tags: ssh, mpi, virtualbox, openmpi

I configured my pc and the `virtualbox` (the first one with Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 and the second one with Ubuntu Server 14.04) in order to communicate through ssh without explicitly ask for password and it works perfectly. Now I'm trying to run a simple hello world using `openmpi`, but when I run the command

```
mpirun --host localhost, name_other_host@ip ./hello
```

it doesn't work. What is wrong in what I'm doing? the executable exists in both hosts in `home/name/Desktop/MW/hello`

the error is this one

```
mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access
or execute an executable:

Executable: ~./hello
Node: domenico-K52Jc

while attempting to start process rank 0.
```

note: domenico-K52Jc is my localhost

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "localhost", you could use your "actual host" name in your /etc/hostname.

e.g. type in terminal:

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

if it returns something like "myubuntu"

then run the command:

```
mpirun --host myubuntu,name_other_host@ip ./hello
```

Also note that there **should not** be a space between your hostnames.

Hope it helps,

Shang